# Why is N- a better nucleophile than S-?

Tags: nucleophilicity

[image]

I can't rationalize why S- is a worse nucleophile than N-. I thought nucelophilicity was related to electronegativity, the more electronegative an atom is, the less of a nucleophile it is. Sulfur is less electronegative than Nitrogen. What concept am I not considering or misunderstanding?

Comment: Well, if that was so simple... In organic chemistry thinking in terms of electronegativity is hardly enough to guess even acidity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be nice to consider the charge density. The S- is more stable than N- because it has more electron shells, so the negative charge density is better distributed in the atom. It makes that the N- is more likely to give up electrons and act as a nucleophile

Comment: Why wouldn't that apply to oxygen versus sulphur?

Comment: I would swear that the carboxylate can stabilize by resonance and thiolate not